# Device specific vibration issue

Tags: java, android

I am building an app that receives SMS messages and enables the user to respond to them. There is also an option to have the device vibrate when a new message is received, thus notifying the user. I have tested the device using a Mi Note 3 and it is not able to vibrate on that device even then the vibration option is turned on. It works fine on all other devices I've tested on, including several ones with Android API 23 installed on them. I believe this is a device specific issue with the underlying hardware of that phone; I would like to know if the Mi Note 3 has underlying problems with its Vibrator hardware/driver that is known.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you show us some code and your Android Manifest?

Comment: I can't do that. Trade secrets you know.